# How big is the gauche interaction of methyl with phenyl in a disubstituted cyclohexane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, energy, conformers

I'd like to compare the equatorial 1-methyl-2-phenylcyclohexane conformation of with axial conformation of 1-**chloro**-3-methylcyclohexane conformation. **In which molecule there is less steric repulsion?**

In other words: **Do you know a guess of energy in kcal/mol for a gauche Ph//Me interaction and for an axial Ph//Cl interaction in this cyclohexane ring?**

I would prefer to have a **comprehensive two-dimensional table for allylic A(1,2) strain**, but I didn't find any. 
It might sound crazy or even unbelievable: A gauche Ph//Me interaction in 1-phenylpropane is only about 0.07 kcal/mol higher in energy than its antiperiplanar conformation (according to: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040402001915509) compared to 0.9 kcal/mol for a gauche Me//Me.

However a diaxial Me//H only weights about 0.9 kcal/mol compaired to 2.7 kcal/mol for a diaxial Ph//H interaction; underlining that phenyl is very often more sterically hindered than a methyl, if the phenyl group can't rotate away.

---

You might be interested why I'm so concernced with my question:
I read the paper http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja035001g and I was curious why in Scheme 5 (with 5a) the phenyl group is placed axial for R1=Me, R2=H.
(In other words I would rather take into account the allylic A13 Ph//H plus gauche Me//Ph than the diaxial Ph//Cl interaction) It's because the the isomerization of the trans hydrazone costs too much energy!

Comment: I just want to make you aware of the fact that the Tetrahedron paper is from 1983(!) and that the MM2 force field is cited from a 1977 paper. I'm not sure if those calculated values can be seen as reliable.

Comment: Does anyone knows a freeware to calculate the relative energy difference?

Comment: GAMESS.  Also, this question can't really be answered without a specification of cis vs trans.